# Why does my schema.ini file not force Excel to read materialized path as text, not date?

Tags: excel, csv

I am working with a CSV file with a column called HierarchyKey, the values of which take the form of materialized paths, eg

```
01
01-01
01-02
02
02-01
02-01-01
```

for sorting and keeping track of hierarchy.

I have written a schema.ini file to try to force Excel to format that column as text, but the values keep getting imported as dates. Is my schema file written correctly? What else can I check?

```
[Geolex_DMU.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
Col1=HierarchyKey Text
```

Answer (score 0):

For text fields you need to also specify the width (number of characters), for example:

Col1=HierarchyKey Text Width 10

Comment: Sadly, that makes no difference. I have tried so many suggestions and still the column is imported as date. I think Excel is completely ignoring the schema.ini file.